# Can YouTube be treated as an audio channel by the system?

Tags: audio, youtube, video-streaming, alerts

I listen to podcasts on YouTube frequently, and with YouTube Premium I can turn off the screen and keep listening. Typically when audio is playing and there's an interruption - say navigation instructions or a workout app reporting lap times - the audio will briefly pause then resume once the interruption is over.

This doesn't happen for YouTube, presumably because it's not being treated the same by the system (audio channel vs. audio/video channel?), so the "high priority" audio plays overtop of the video's audio.

Is it possible to change this behavior so videos (or at least their audio) pause during these alerts? On YouTube or across the system?

Comment: Are you not using Android 12 or higher version? [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#audio-focus-12) claims that system enforces audio fade out behavior on Android 12 and higher.

Comment: Oof, many apoloiges - this behavior is on a Pixel 6 Pro running Android 13 (TQ2A.230405.003.E1).

Looking at that documentation, it seems to still be "ducking" (making one audio stream quieter while another has focus) as opposed to pausing it temporarily, as described with "speech content": _Note that automatic ducking is not performed when listening to speech content, because the user might miss some of the program. For example, if you duck playback while giving driving directions._